# Simultaneously update multiple database records deriving their values from foreach input field using codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am a low-level code enthusiast trying to develop a student performance application. It would capture individual student mark per subject and generate comprehensive report forms once the marks for all subjects are entered.

It would simplify things for teachers if there was a provision to enter student marks for all the students in a class and post them all at once (update all button) instead of posting each student mark individually (update button). That is where my dilemma is.

Student mark list form

[image]

In my controller, the update code is :

```
if ($this->input->post('operation') == 'update') {
$data['mark_obtained'] = $this->input->post('mark_obtained');
$data['mark_total'] = $this->input->post('mark_total');

if($data['mark_obtained']<=$data['mark_total'] && $data['mark_obtained']>=0){
$this->db->where('mark_id', $this->input->post('mark_id'));
$this->db->update('mark', $data);
}
```

The update button works fine. I just don't seem to conceptualize how to make the 'update all' work. Please help.

```
<?php 
$my_tabindex=1;

foreach($marks as $student_mark):
<tr>
    <td  class="span3">
        <?php 
            //this is derived from another query that returns information      over students of a selected class
            echo $row['student_name'];  
        ?>
    </td>
    <td>
          <input type="number" step = "0.01" value="<?php echo $student_mark['mark_obtained'];?>" name="mark_obtained" tabindex="<?php echo $my_tabindex+1; ?>" />
    </td>
<td>
    <input type="hidden" name="operation" value="update" />
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-normal btn-gray"> Update</button>
</td>
</tr>
?>
<?php 
endforeach;
?>
```

Comment: Please use Input as array that will solve your problem .Thanks

Comment: update batch should do it

Comment: <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Titel" name="mark_obtained[]">   i am suggesting you like this . Do you understand it.

Comment: Thank you @Hassan Ali for your insight. Will try it out and revert back.

Comment: My concern in this approach however is the ability to retain both the 'update' and 'update all' functionalities. The reason for this is that sometimes only a single record may require to be updated, say in the case of an amendment. How will it work?

Answer (score 0):

Just a heads up, this is my first answer ever, so I apologize in advance for formatting/rule breaking.

To expand on Hassan ALi's comment. You should post an array of values versus a single value.

Codeigniter has this functionality:
*"To return an array of multiple POST parameters, pass all the required keys as an array. $this->input->post(array('field1', 'field2'));"* https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/input.html

I would consider using the mark_id as the key when you create the arrays.
For instance, if you have an array named $marks_obtained_array, than you could insert key value pairs 'id' -> 'mark'.

Then, if you also have an array of the mark_id's, then you can easily loop through them in the controller to make updates.

```
if ($this->input->post('operation') == 'update_all') {
     foreach($mark_ids_array as $mark_id){
         $data['mark_obtained'] = $marks_obtained_array[$mark_id];
         $data['mark_total'] = $marks_total_arry[$mark_id];

         if($data['mark_obtained']<=$data['mark_total'] && $data['mark_obtained']>=0){
              $this->db->where('mark_id', $mark_id);
              $this->db->update('mark', $data);
          }
....
}
```